# Changing Synchronous operations into Asynchronous in Business Service & Repository Layers (ASP.NET MVC 2)

Tags: c#, multithreading, asp.net-mvc-2, asynchronous

I am working on a Travel related website and here is my high level architecture:

```
ASP.NET MVC 2 (Presentation Layer)  
Services Layer  
Repository Layer communicating with external J2EE Services
```

Currently all of my layers support ONLY Synchronous communication like this:

```
//Pricing Controller...
public ActionResult GetRates()
{
    //Contruct Pricing Request            
    //PricingRequest request = Contruct Pricing Request...; 
    PricingResponse response = _pricingService.GetComponentPricing(request);
    //....
    //...
    return View(response);
}

//Pricing Service...
public PricingResponse GetComponentPricing(PricingRequest pricingRequest)
{
    //Do Something...
    PricingResponseDomainObject responseDomainObject = _pricingRepository.GetComponentPricing(pricingRequest.ConvertToPricingRequestDomainObject());
    //Apply Business Rules and perform some action on response
    //Convert DomainObjectResponse into ServiceObjectResponse...
    return response(PricingResponse);
}

//Pricing Repository...
public PricingResponseDomainObject GetComponentPricing(PricingRequestDomainObject pricingRequest)
{
    //Do Something...
    //Call J2EE Service and Get Response
    //Return Response
    return response(PricingResponseDomainObject);
}
```

Now I have a need to change my Pricing Controller to AsyncController and convert `public ActionResult GetRates()` into Asynchronous Action.

What changes do I need to do in my Service & Repository layers in order to support Asynchronous operations? Do I have to re-write them completely?

**Edit: Need for changing Controller into Asynchronous**

For a particular Search scenario, I need to call the J2EE service 1 to 5 times (independent operations), consolidate all responses into a single response and hand it over to the Controller to be able to present it to user.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?  What problem are you trying to solve?  Changing to asynchronous controllers may not be a proper solution.

Comment: @qes - more than likely, some of his service calls take a long time to complete.  This is what async controllers are for.

Comment: I asked to avoid making such assumptions.

Comment: qes & Mystere Man, I have updated the need for converting my controller into Asynchronous and I hope its the right way. Pls. advice if you guys think otherwise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you likely will not have to do anything.  In fact, converting them to async themselves would make your code a lot more complicated.  The idea behind an async controller is that the controller action returns when it's done processing, and since those methods will still be syncronous that works out just fine.  You do your work, and return when you're finished.

Comment: What if his app makes use of thread local variables? I believe blindly switching to asynchronous controller actions would be problematic if it does.

Comment: @qes - I would say that using thread local variables in a web application is a recipe for trouble in a lot of ways.  Remember, requests are serviced by a thread pool, which means threads are not destroyed after each request.

Comment: I've seen plenty of UnitOfWork implementations for ORM's that use them.

Comment: @qes - If that's the case, then I would consider those ORM's to be broken, particularly if they don't put big flashing neon signs in the documentation warning of this.  There are so many ways that TLS assumptions can shoot you in the foot, and any framework making use of them, without notifying the user of that fact is irresponsible.. particularly in this day and age of multi-core processors and focus on parallel and async programming methods.

Comment: Mystere Man, Most of the documentation I read online says that service that exposes methods need to implement an event-based asynchronous pattern. Pls. see following link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee728598.aspx#converting_synchronous_action_methods_to_asynchronous_action_methods

Comment: @Alex - I think you misunderstand my point.  You can make your controller async without making your services async easily, just spawn a single new thread to handle the the services syncronously.  The controll is async because your services are handled in an async thread, letting the threadpool thread return to service other requests.  Yes, you can also rewrite your services to be async, but that's a lot more work.

Comment: Will you be able to provide some pseudo code for doing this without making my services asynchronous? I am little confused.

Comment: Mystere Man, currently I call my BLL method like this inside my Controller:: `PricingResponse response = _pricingService.GetComponentPricing(request); ` Can I continue to call it same way in GetRatesAsync() Action after I change my controller to Async?

Comment: @Alex - Yes, you can continue to call it the same way, but you must do it with a new thread (but don't use a thread pool thread because that would defeat the purpose).  Check Darins answer to this question for an example of how to do this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4772916/async-controllers-in-asp-net-mvc

Comment: Also, similar to Darins approach, I will be calling my BLL method in loop for 1 to 5 times inside AsyncController, Do I need to call AsyncManager.Sync()? Would I run into a race condition?

Comment: @Alex - Only you know if you will run into a race condition.  You don't have to spawn a thread for each time, you could spawn a single thread and call it 1-5 time sequentially in a single thread.

Comment: Hello Mystere Man, I implemented the final solution in a little different way and would greatly appreciate your feedback. Here is my solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5807977/calling-non-async-operations-from-asynccontroller-like-to-validate-my-approach